# Magento2 deploy command not working and rest commands are working

Tags: magento2, deploy, ssh, command

I have tried to run this **php bin/magento setup:static-contnet:deploy** command on the magento root folder then it showing the below error

> "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /home/nuluv938/public_html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Console/Command/DeployStaticContentCommand.php
>   on line 403"

While rest commands are working fine.

Without running the deploy command I am unable to create the front-end folder inside the **pub/static** path directory.

Comment: Which is your magento and  php version ?

Comment: versions: magento2.2.2 and PHP Version 7.0.27. Yesterday  it was working perfect but Now it is not working.

Comment: @Banvari Have you got any solution for this I am also facing same issue. I will be very thankful for you help.

Comment: please check var log for more information about error.

Comment: run this command  php bin/magento setup:static-contnet:deploy -f

Answer (score 5):

This issue generally occurs when you keep backup folders in module/theme view files

```
app/code/{{namespace}}/{{module}}/view

or 

app/design/...
```

Remove backup files and try again, it would be working fine.

Comment: Yes it worked for e as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have got error like

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in
>   /html/vendor/magento/module-deploy/Source/Modules.php on line 49

app static folder or view has the wrong name or contains another folder compare to the view structure
[image]

check folder name and run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f**

it's work for me. I hope it will help you